# MICRODATE in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem, the date is saved in the form `1556447923594` (microdate). I want to retrieve this date from the database and display it in php.

```
$datetime = gmdate("Y-M-D G:i:s", $row['time']);
if($row['time'] == "0"){
    echo "<td>Permban</td>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td>$datetime</td>";
}
```

And I have = `51290-Aug-Fri 18:38:20`   not this `2019-04-28 01:22:12`

Comment: Just divide it by 1000.

Comment: Your date format is also wrong `Y-M-D G:i:s` you are looking for `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: I changed and still the same 51290-Aug-Fri 18:38:20

Comment: https://3v4l.org/E219r

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 1):

You just need to divide the value by 1000 to convert it to seconds so it can be used by [`gmdate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php). Also, to get the output in the form you want, you should change the format string to `Y-m-d H:i:s`:

```
$row['time'] = 1556447923594;
echo $datetime = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $row['time']/1000);
```

Output:

```
2019-04-28 10:38:43
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/E219r)